# Can I apply PCA to combine correlated variables into one variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, pca, least-squares, high-dimensional

I have a dataset with 11 observations and 11 features. I want to use linear regression for estimating the coefficients by using OLS method.

I know it is not advisable to use linear regression with such a big number of features, comparing with the number of records. I have about 6 features that are highly correlated (correlation > 0.88). But I don't want to delete these columns, as I can loose information.

So can I use PCA on these 6 highly correlated features to transform them into one column? Then, I want to combine this column with other features and use linear regression.

Comment: What is the goal here?

Comment: You mean the goal of research or the goal of applying PCA? The latter I already described in the question. The goal of research is to estimate the effect of governmental programs on poverty rates.

Comment: The goal of research.  With a dataset so tiny, I don't see scope for any more than single-predictor regressions.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Can you find serious published research based on such tiny datasets and multiple regression? Sorry, but there is no good news on that point.

Comment: There is much scope for a question easier to answer here. Post all your data, say more about your goal and ask for advice. (In turn whether you'd be better off in an economics or econometrics or political science or sociology forum is hard to tell.)

Comment: I think you're right about the fact that I should ask for advice in political science forums. But, still, my question is still valid. I'm still curious, whether it works for high dimensional dataset with observations >100 and features = observations-1.

Comment: In order to properly identify a regression line/hyperplane from data general advice is to have some 15-20 observations per dimension. Something can be done with say 10 even though normally very imprecise, so you may just about get away with one predictor, as @NickCox wrote.

Comment: Your last comment raises a new question, and the short answer is the same. You need many observations for each parameter estimated. (It's the community that decides whether a question is valid....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can use the first principal component of your predictors as the sole predictor (I don't think multiple regression with more than one predictor variable makes sense with 11 observations). However, the interpretation of this is then determined by the data, which determine the principal component. One thing I recommend in such cases is to think hard about how to create a meaningful index for what is relevant to you from your variables rather than using PCA to do it automatically, as the meaningful index will normally give you better interpretation. If however you think you *need* more than one predictor for what you want to achieve (like interpreting relative importance of the different variables), you are pretty much lost with 11 observations.

Generally, in regression problems where the number of dimensions is critically high compared with the number of observations, there are various techniques for dimension reduction and variable selection. PCA is one of them, but this is typically done in situations in which interpretation of the impact of single predictor variables is not a central issue. Also you are much better off in terms of information in the data with, say, 500 observations and 600 variables than with 11 and 11. Statistics is not magic. If you plot your data you should already get a feeling for how difficult it is to precisely locate the line with one predictor and 11 observations (unless residual variance is very small). Making statements about how more predictors work together to explain the observations, taking into account their correlation, is near impossible. Also any diagnosis of the model assumptions will be extremely unreliable if possible at all.

Comment: Well, I have only ONE variable, where interpretation is crucial, but the other ones are covariates. The relationship between the covariates and the target variable is already proven, so I don't need to interpret ones.